# Firebase not sending OTP to the phone number in device

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I have implemented firebase otp in my flutter application

- When I install the app on my device and requested for the same number on that deice it does not send me the message. But when I change the number it send the message
- So I changed the device and tried to send the previous number, it sent message successfully. Then I used the number on second device and it did not send the message

*** When I use the same number on the device it does not send the OTP**

Here is the code for sending the otp

```
  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verID) {
      this.verificationId = verID;
    };
    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
    };
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess =
        (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
      print('verified');
    };
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verifyFailed = (AuthException exception) {
      print('${exception.message}');
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: widget.phone,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
        verificationFailed: verifyFailed,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve);

    log("OTP sent");
  }
```

This is the code for verifying the OTP

```
signIn() async{
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: enteredOtp,
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) {
      //SOME CODE HERE
    }).catchError((e) {
      showAlert(
        context: context,
        title: "Empty or Invalid OTP",
      );
      log("Invalid OTP");
    });
  }
```

What's wrong in here? How do I fix this and get the otp for the same number in device.

Comment: what exception are you getting in log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in point of fact, I believe that's actually expected, and intended usage.  (Or close to it) as if Firebase can confirm phone identity via push notifications, it doesn't even send the text, as it's already verified.  (Usually only happens if it's verified the phone once).  But if you're sending it to a phone number other than the phone number the device is connecting to, then it can't use the previous verificationID in the system.

So I would suggest checking to see which parts of the code function and not.  Check to see if the code and authorization fails, or if it will continue to the next part of the program fully authorized.  Add some print statements in there just to make sure.  But I'm pretty sure that should be the way it works.